# How do you get the names of all gif images in a folder in python 2?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a folder like C:\Temp\My Pictures and it has a bunch of gif pictures in it. I need to be able to get the name of the gif images in a string and I have no idea how. I looked everywhere and couldn't find an answer, please help!

Comment: Did you look at the `os` module?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still confused though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("C:\Temp\My Pictures"):
    if file.endswith(".gif"):
        print file
```

You can read more, about os.listdir at the official docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Answer (score 0):

As PotatoIng_ is correct you may want to end up with a list of strings.

Try using this (works with Python 2 and 3):

```
import os

root, dirs, files=next(os.walk('C:\Temp\My Pictures'))
gifs=list(filter(lambda filename:filename.endswith('.gif'), files))
```

`os.walk` walks down the directory tree, but you only need the first result( that's the `next`). Now filter the `files` list and use those entries with `filename.endswith('.gif')` is `True`. `filter` returns an iterator in python 3 so use `list` to turn it into a list.

Result will be e.g.:

```
>>> gifs
['a.gif', 'b.gif', 'c.gif']
```